# jQuery: How to get the difference between two time and date with am/pm format

Tags: jquery, date

I want to get the the difference between two time and date with am/pm format and get a 24 hour format result. for example: Given the time start 01/01/2007(mm/dd/yyyy) at 08:30:20 AM and the time end 01/02/2007 at 05:30:30 PM, then the result would be 21:00:10.

```js
var timeStart = new Date("01/01/2007 " + "08:30:20 AM");
var timeEnd = new Date("01/02/2007 " + "05:30:30 PM");

var diff = (timeEnd - timeStart);
var seconds = diff / 6000;
var minutes = (diff - seconds)/ 60;
var hours = (diff - minutes) / 60;

$("#start").text(timeStart);
$("#end").text(timeEnd);
$("#diff").text(diff);
$("#sec").text(seconds);
$("#min").text(minutes);
$("#hr").text(hours);
```

```css
div{
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Time Start: <div id="start"></div><br>
Time End: <div id="end"></div><br>
Difference: <div id="diff"></div><br>
Seconds: <div id="sec"></div><br>
Minutes: <div id="min"></div><br>
Hours: <div id="hr"><div><br>
```

Comment: The correct result is 33h00m10s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this [site](http://www.tim-carter.com/index.php?t=DateDiff%20with%20Javascript%20and%20jQuery&Menu=2&SubMenuId=2&ItemId=91)

```js
var timeStart = new Date("01/01/2007 " + "08:30:20 AM");
var timeEnd = new Date("01/02/2007 " + "05:30:30 PM");


function datediff(fromDate,toDate,interval) { 
  /*
                 * DateFormat month/day/year hh:mm:ss
                 * ex.
                 * datediff('01/01/2011 12:00:00','01/01/2011 13:30:00','seconds');
                 */
  
  var second=1000, minute=second*60, hour=minute*60, day=hour*24, week=day*7; 
  fromDate = new Date(fromDate); 
  toDate = new Date(toDate); 
  var timediff = toDate - fromDate; 

  if (isNaN(timediff)) return NaN; 
  switch (interval) { 
    case "years": return toDate.getFullYear() - fromDate.getFullYear(); 
    case "months": return ( 
      ( toDate.getFullYear() * 12 + toDate.getMonth() ) 
      - 
      ( fromDate.getFullYear() * 12 + fromDate.getMonth() ) 
    ); 
    case "weeks"  : return Math.floor(timediff / week); 
    case "days"   : return Math.floor(timediff / day);  
    case "hours"  : return Math.floor(timediff / hour);  
    case "minutes": return Math.floor(timediff / minute); 
    case "seconds": return Math.floor(timediff / second); 
    default: return undefined; 
  } 
}


$("#start").text(timeStart);
$("#end").text(timeEnd);
$("#diff").text(timeEnd - timeStart);
$("#sec").text(datediff(timeStart, timeEnd, 'seconds') % 60);
$("#min").text(datediff(timeStart, timeEnd, 'minutes') % 60);
$("#hr").text(datediff(timeStart, timeEnd, 'hours'));
```

```css
div{
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Time Start: <div id="start"></div><br>
Time End: <div id="end"></div><br>
Difference: <div id="diff"></div><br>
Seconds: <div id="sec"></div><br>
Minutes: <div id="min"></div><br>
Hours: <div id="hr"><div><br>
```

Comment: how about the hours? that should be 21. If I'm going to subtract the hours by 12, how about if the dates are the same? that might result to -3.

Comment: From 01/01/2007(mm/dd/yyyy) at 08:30:20 AM  to 01/02/2007(mm/dd/yyyy) at 08:30:20 AM is 24h. Plus 9h10s to 17:30:30. Isn't is correct?

Comment: It would be 21h00m10s if the timeEnd were `new Date("01/02/2007 " + "05:30:30 AM")`. Right?

Comment: the result of the hour is 33 but the correct result should be 21. if the dates are the same, the result of the hour is 9 which is correct but the dates in the given variables are not the same.

Comment: WHY the correct is 21???? There are 33h from you timeStart to your timeEnd. Why are you subtracting 12h from the result? I think you should clarify your question.

Comment: ow! sorry dude, I forgot that 8:30AM to 8:30am to the next morning is 24 hours. Sorry dude, my mistake.

Comment: No prob. Glad could help.